# Are there any efficient random BYTES generator (without using divisions)?

Tags: random, generator

I'm trying to generate some 8-bit random numbers with C++ and don't want to use divisions (like rand()%8 or any  scale methods).

One algorithm I found online is [Park-Miller-Carta Pseudo-Random Number Generator](http://www.firstpr.com.au/dsp/rand31/)

It is a 32-bit random number generator with no divisions. With these random numbers, I'm trying to extract the lower or higher 8 bits of them so that I can get some random bytes, but this does not seem to work because these bits are not so random.

Are there any tricks to fix this or are there any other algorithms that can do the trick?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to avoid division/modulo?

Comment: Are you just trying to avoid using "%8"? If so, the compiler won't use a divide anyway. Compilers are smart about powers of 2 and will use "& 7" instead.

Comment: Since I'm doing some system-level experiments. Division is too slow.

Comment: Yeah, I tried &7, but the result is not so random because it essentially extracts the lower bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about XORing four bytes of 32bit random integer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you mean using the higher 8 bits to XOR lower 8 bits?

Comment: I think I'll move on with the lower 8 bits. Thank you all.